# ERROR expected primary-expression before '[' token C PROGRAM (DEV C++)

Tags: c, arrays, variable-assignment

I've just had this simple assignment and it's not complete yet as you see, but I have faced this problem

> 65 17  [Error] expected primary-expression before '[' token
>
> 69 23  [Error] expected primary-expression before '[' token

This is my code below; I can't see the problem could you please help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void viewAll();
void viewStd();

int student[4][5] = {{1232 , 10 , 23 , 45 , 56 },  //global
                     {2343 , 45 , 43 , 24 , 78 },
                     {2345 , 34 , 45 , 45 , 45 },
                     {3423 , 67 , 6  , 65 , 56 }};
int main()
{
    int choice;
    system("CLS");
    printf("===========================");
    printf("\n\t  MENU\n");
    printf("===========================");

    printf("\n1. View all students records\n2. View a student records by ID\n3. Show the highest and the lowest final scores");
    printf("\n\n Please enter your choice: ");

    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: viewAll();break;
        case 2: viewStd();break;
        /*case 3: HLscore();break;*/
        default: printf("Input not recognized");
    }

    getch();
} 

void viewAll()
{
    char choice;
    system("CLS");
    printf("=========================================================");
    printf("\n|StudentID |  Quiz1   |  Quiz2   | Mid-Term |   Final  |\n");
    printf("=========================================================\n");

    printf("|   1232   |    10    |    23    |    45    |    56    |\n");
    printf("|   2343   |    45    |    43    |    24    |    78    |\n");
    printf("|   2345   |    34    |    45    |    45    |    45    |\n");
    printf("|   3423   |    67    |     6    |    65    |    56    |\n");

    printf("\n\nPress (R) to return, press (E) to exit: ");
    scanf("%s", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 'R': main();break;
        case 'E': exit(1);break;
        default: printf("Input not recognized");
    }
}

void viewStd()
{
    int id;
    printf("\n\nPlease enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if (id == std[i][0])
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                printf("%d  ", std[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FINAL MODIFICATION:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void viewAll();
void viewStd();
void HLscore();

int student[4][5]={{1232 , 10 , 23 , 45 , 56 },  //global
               {2343 , 45 , 43 , 24 , 78 },
               {2345 , 34 , 45 , 45 , 45 },
               {3423 , 67 , 6  , 65 , 56 }};
 int main()
{
int choice;
system("CLS");
printf("===========================");
printf("\n\t  MENU\n");
printf("===========================");

printf("\n1. View all students records\n2. View a student records by ID\n3. Show the highest and the lowest final scores");
printf("\n\n Please enter your choice: ");

scanf("%d",&choice);

switch(choice){
    case 1: viewAll();break;
    case 2: viewStd();break;
    case 3: HLscore();break;
    default: printf("Input not recognized");
}

getch();
}

void viewAll()
{
char choice;
system("CLS");
printf("=========================================================");
printf("\n|StudentID |  Quiz1   |  Quiz2   | Mid-Term |   Final  |\n");
printf("=========================================================\n");

printf("|   1232   |    10    |    23    |    45    |    56    |\n");
printf("|   2343   |    45    |    43    |    24    |    78    |\n");
printf("|   2345   |    34    |    45    |    45    |    45    |\n");
printf("|   3423   |    67    |     6    |    65    |    56    |\n");

printf("\n\nPress (R) to return, press (E) to exit: ");
scanf("%s",&choice);
switch(choice){
    case 'R': main();break;
    case 'E': exit(1);break;
    default:printf("Input not recognized");
}
}

void viewStd()
{
int id;
char choice;
printf("\n\nPlease enter ID: ");
scanf("%d",&id);

printf("=========================================================");
printf("\n|StudentID |  Quiz1   |  Quiz2   | Mid-Term |   Final  |\n");
printf("=========================================================\n");


for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
   {

        if (id == student[i][0])
        {
            for (int j=0; j<5; ++j)
            {
                printf("    %d     ",student[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n_________________________________________________________");
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n\n To search for other students press (S), To return press (R), To exit press (E):  ");
    scanf("%s",&choice);
    
    switch(choice){
    case 'S': viewStd();break;
    case 'R': main();break;
    case 'E': exit(1);break;
    default: printf("ERROR");}
     }
    
    void HLscore()
    {
        int max,min;
        char choice;
        
        max=student[0][1];
        for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<5; ++j)
            {
                if(student[i][j]>max)
                {
                    max=student[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        
        min=student[0][1];
        for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<5; ++j)
            {
                if(student[i][j]<min)
                {
                    min=student[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\nHighest mark is %d",max);
        printf("\nLowest mark is %d",min);
        
        printf("\n\nPress (R) to return, press (E) to exit: ");
        scanf("%s",&choice);
switch(choice){
    case 'R': main();break;
    case 'E': exit(1);break;
    default:printf("Input not recognized");
}
    }
```

Comment: `std` typo as `student`

Comment: Thank you sir, would you take a look at the edit? any suggestions?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&choice);` is buffer overrun.

Comment: but it's a local variable, can you refer me to an explanation of this situation?
sorry I'm a novice programmer

Comment: `%s`  writes NUL(`\0`) at the end. So two characters are written in one character area(overrun). [DEMO](http://ideone.com/hS03Gc)

Comment: what is the solution then?

Comment: Replace `scanf("%s",&choice);` with `scanf(" %c", &choice);`

Comment: I was doing this in my programs till i faced this problem

`printf("Continue?");`
 `scanf("%s",&j);}`
 `while (j=='y');`

when I put `%c` instead of `%s` the program would terminate, is this a different case?

ps: the sentences is a part of do{}while()

Comment: Use `" %c"` instead of `"%c"`

Comment: Ok, is there an explanation?

Comment: Previous space in format skips white-spaces characters. First Read [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Well that was very informative, these few tips are better than a whole lecture :)
Thank you alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to access `std` via `id == std[i][0]`, But I don't see std declared anywhere. (Did you mean `student`?)

Comment: For real man I'm soo dumb :(
I'm sorry your right I changed the function name but I forgot to change the calling statement.

Comment: This is very well readable. Right now you're programming with "Allman" style, I do the same and I concider it best. Just watch out for those pesky K&R programmers. Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really appreciate the information.

Comment: I would be thankful If you take a look at the final edit